# java - deleting an element of an array from any position and shifting the remaining elements

Tags: java, arrays

I'm trying to shift the elements of an array after deleting one element from the array by setting the value to 0. I can only get this to work if I delete an element from the beginning of the array with this block of code.

```
if (balance[index] == 0 && acctNum[index] != 0) {
    numaccts--;
    acctNum[index] = 0;
    for(int count=0;count<numaccts;count++){
        acctNum[count]=acctNum[count+1];
        balance[count]=balance[count+1];
    }
acctNum[numaccts]=0;
balance[numaccts]=0;
}
```

This is the good output I get when I delete the first value from the array (there was a value before 567834).

```
567834    100.50
111111    0.0
222222    0.0
333333    0.0
444444    0.0
```

if I delete any value other than the first, the array isn't properly shifted and this is the result. There should be a number before 567834 and the "0  0.00" shouldn't be there.

```
567834    100.5
0    0.0
222222    0.0
333333    0.0
444444    0.0
```

I believe the issue is with this first block of code in this post, but I'm having trouble fixing it. I don't think creating a temporary variable will fix the issue. Any ideas?

Comment: Is there a reason you're using arrays instead of a map or list of pojos?

Comment: start at count = index not count = 0 Also acctNum[index] = 0; is unnecessary if the shift works

Comment: @shmosel Only because it's required. Can't use an array list either.

Comment: @JeremyKahan I appreciate your response, but it seems that making count=index changed nothing.

Comment: hmmm, weird. acctNum[index]=0 is needed after all for the case where index is the last one and the loop does not execute, I think. But I don't get why what I suggested did not work. Especially if count is beyond 0, I don't see how the first value could get lost.

Comment: You said for(int count=index;count<numaccts;count++)?

Comment: @JeremyKahan there is more code that this method calls to, but i have thoroughly tested everything before this so it's probably not necessary to show. I'm sure it has to do with my attempt to shift. I could add an if statement to the block of code that prints the numbers but that'll only get rid of "0  0.00" which doesn't really solve the whole problem

Comment: @JeremyKahan and yes i said for(int count=index;count<numaccts;count++)

Comment: Okay. I must be missing something. I hope someone else sees it for you. Sorry.

Comment: No worries. Thanks for your time.

Comment: @JeremyKahan D'oh! You are correct! I changed count=0 to count=index in the wrong block of code. Thank you so much!

Comment: ubetcha. I'm glad we figured it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only want to shift stuff over from beyond the newly created hole. You may need to take a little care, still, that the below handles the very last slot without reading beyond the end of the array. But this should be a good start.

```
    if (balance[index] == 0 && acctNum[index] != 0) {
    numaccts--;
    acctNum[index] = 0;//handles case when index is at the end
    for(int count=index;count<numaccts;count++){//start from hole, shift over from beyond there
        acctNum[count]=acctNum[count+1];
        balance[count]=balance[count+1];
    }
acctNum[numaccts]=0;
balance[numaccts]=0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem was that you are assign 0 to count variable within the for loop instead of giving the index of the element which is you are need to delete.

```
private void deleteAndShift(int [] balance, int [] acctNum, int index, int numaccts) {
    if(isValidAccount(balance, acctNum, index)) {
        numaccts--;
        acctNum[index] = 0;
        for(int count=index;count<numaccts;count++){
            acctNum[count]=acctNum[count+1];
            balance[count]=balance[count+1];
        }
    acctNum[numaccts]=0;
    balance[numaccts]=0;

    }
}

private boolean isValidAccount(int[] balance, int[] acctNum, int index) {
    return balance[index] == 0 && acctNum[index] != 0;
}
```